# Layout blurry/low quality when jQuery mobile on android using phonegap

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using phonegap and jQuery mobile to develop an Android application. In the browser, the pages look fine, but when I run the app on a device (=in a webview), the pages look cheap and kind of... off. Almost as if the page is zoomed 101% or something like that. Has anyone else run into this problem? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you got it working fine. i also got the same problem. it looks fine in emulator, but messed up in device. I tried setting the @dSquared suggestions. Its better than the initial attempt. but the form control & button edges are blurry... any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried adding the `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` value to the viewport meta tag in the `</head>` of the page like this:

```
<head>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    ...
</head>
```

That should do the trick; I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Looks crisp now, but tiny. How do I make the jquery controls and font appear larger? Or will that make them blurry again?

Comment: @Stefan Try placing `initial-scale=1.0` and/or `maximum-scale=1.0` in the viewport meta tag as well. Also ensure you have `width=device-width` in there if your app is meant to be full width.

Comment: I have all of that in there. I tried setting initial-scale to 1.5, but now it looks crappy again. A little better at 1.6, though...

Comment: @Stefan `initial-scale=1.0` means it is at 100% (1px = 1px). To keep the crisp look you'll need to enlarge everything in your code to match the size of the device. Applying any zoom or density change will make the items blurry again.

Comment: I was hoping jquery mobile would take care of that. Weird that I have to fix all of this manually.

Comment: @Stefan JQM does a lot of the groundwork; you'll just need to modify its CSS (or create your own) to style the app to match your final design.

Comment: man... this command has fixed a lot of stuff on my cordova app

Answer (score 2):

Actually folks, the real fix without any font-size side effects, is addressing the
CSS Text-shadow as follows.

```
* {
text-shadow:0 0 0 transparent;
text-shadow:none;
}
```

This makes sure your font has no drop shadow, which is why text looks blurry. If you look closely, you can see text is not actually blurry, but has drop shadow of the same color.

Answer (score 1):

It was also suggested on a [jQuery forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/android-visual-quality-problems-pages-looks-cheep-pixelated-forms-images-with-tons-of-blur) to add `user-scalable=0` to the ever increasing meta tag.  So it eventually looks something akin to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=0">
```

This fixit worked for me.  Though the jQuery forum post also suggested the final work around may be to include some Android specific css:

```
- if is_android?
  %link{:rel => 'stylesheet', :type => 'text/css', :href => '/stylesheets/mobile/android.css'}/
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have same problem when testing on mobile device. But refer to this [link](http://darkforge.blogspot.com/2010/05/customize-android-browser-scaling-with.html) :

> The CSS "px" unit may differ from a device's actual pixels, as the
>   browser "scales" images and fonts to a larger size than you requested.
>   (The browser just naturally assumes you didn't really mean "pixels"
>   when you said "px," and helpfully tries to resize your content to make
>   it readable on high-resolution phone screens.)

Then, I changed my TARGET-DENSITYDPI to "target-densitydpi=150"  and it works properly (tested on NEXUS 10).

Answer (score 0):

try to put blank character " " in the same contrainer of your image, I don't know exactly but it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Webkit uses 'css pixels', which is then re-calculated to the phisical device resolution - maybe that is the problem here.

If you have a typical 4" mobile phone with a 480x800 screen, the css pixels could be 320x533, and CSS pixel ratio would be 1.5.

In this case a 32 x 32px image need to have at least 48 x 48px to look good and sharp. Because some devices have pixel ratio 2 (iPhone 4/5), I usually use 2x bigger images and they look very good, almost as good as svg images (and there are no problems width older browsers).

Doing this, you need to remember to define the image size

```
background:url('myimage64.png'); background-size:32px 32px;
```

or

```
<img src='myimage64.png' width='32' height='32'>
```